# Running SeleniumIDE test case from a shortcut

Tags: firefox, browser, automation, selenium-ide

So what I am trying to accomplish here is to run a script in seleniumIDE automatically from the click of a button or a desktop shortcut preferably. Right now, I have seleniumIDE installed in firefox and each time, I am having to open my script manually on seleniumIDE and then having to click on "Run Test Case" for my script to get it working. I trying to avoid these steps and instead maybe let's say run the script directly from the click of just one button. If someone could give me any idea or anything, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

> java -jar ./selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar -port 4444
>   -htmlSuite *firefox http://www.yoursite.com ./your_suite_file.html ./your_result_file.html

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Running_IDE_scripts_with_Selenium_RC